# Chrome won't load pages after Stop Debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, google-chrome

If I F5 to debug, and browse to my test site using Chrome, and execution halts before sending a response (e.g. we get an exception and I click Stop Debugging instead of continue to the end), that Chrome window and any child windows it spawns will no longer work with the project. It will say "Loading" with the spinner in the tab, the window will be empty, and it will stay like this apparently forever. Alternately, in a new tab, I type the URL and hit enter and it does not display any loading behaviour as though it isn't even trying to load it. This persists across tabs within the same window hierarchy.

My workaround is to create incognito windows in Chrome when testing local sites. If it gets into this error state, then I have to close the window and open a new incognito session from the original browser parent. If I accidentally cause this problem in the main window, I have to fully close Chrome to proceed. Using different Chrome profiles also works as I assume it's a different top level process.

Otherwise, it does seem to calm itself after quite a while - 5+ real life minutes or something similar it will revert and start working again and the page will load if it was still trying. But is there a better solution? This is VS 2022, debugging ASPX/C#, using a hosts file for local.site.com domains and separate http/https ports.

Edit: Image to show settings page

[image: settings]

Comment: What error did Visual Studio give you when you sent the response? Hope you can give more information.

Comment: I've had this happen as well and had to resort to killing chrome via task manager. No clue why it happens.

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT not sure I understand your question. This applies for any exception or breakpoint that pauses execution, after which I click the big red stop button. When loading the page after this, it never hits the server - it's as if Chrome doesn't even try to request it. It looks like a Chrome bug to me but I'm not sure.

Comment: @NickP First follow the steps below to set it up:
Debug ==> your name of project + Debug Properties==>IIS Express==>Hosting Model==>Out Of Process
However, if the above steps do not solve the problem, it may be that some software running on your computer is affecting the operation of Google Chrome. It is recommended that you uninstall any software that was installed before this problem occurred.

Comment: IIS Express is selected but I don't have the Hosting Model option. Does this advice apply to VS 2022? This behaviour has been there since Day 1, unfortunately. It's nothing to do with recent software. I have to either exit Visual Studio (closing IISExpress from the system tray is not enough) or start a new browser process (this also happens to Firefox).

Comment: @NickP I will post a new answer with pictures. If you are sure that there is no Hosting Model, I will think of other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is rare, we need to troubleshoot step by step. First, please confirm that Tools==>Options==>Debugging==>General==>Enable Edit and Continue is enabled. Then you need to use detach all instead of stop debugging.

Comment: Mine looks completely different. I have edited the original post to show how it looks (I changed the domain name in the test site for privacy).

Comment: @NickP Has your issue been solved？

Comment: No. The problem has occurred since I installed VS 2022 over a year ago so it's not recent or due to any software changes. I just finally got annoyed enough to post about it.

Comment: @NickP Hi, I have edited a new answer. If it doesn't work, we move on to the next step.

Comment: I had a look, and Enable Edit and Continue was enabled. However I guess I don't really need this so I disabled it. Now when I 'stop' debugging, the website still works and ASPX file changes are reflected but not code changes, as expected, until I F5 again. So although it's not exactly what I wanted, I think this workaround is fine, I will test a little and confirm.

Comment: @NickP If you already have a better solution, you can share it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you hit a break-point in code behind, then code has haulted, and no more web pages can be dished out. (this is standard behavour when using the built-in web server that launches by hitting F5. if you close the web page, then the web server shuts down, debugging stop, and you back into Visual Studio.

You could try hitting ctrl-F5. That runs the VS site as non debug mode, and break-points etc. thus don't usually get hit. But, f5 STARTS a copy of IIS express web server. You close that web page, then debugging stop, IIS is then shut down. This is correct behavior's.

If you want to start testing the web site with say NOT having a debugger tied to the web site, then you probably are better off to install + run IIS full edition, and not the Express Edition that is "tied" to VS and the debugger.

So, the instant you close the browsesr, or even hit the "stop" button in VS, then IIS is shut down - it is stopped each time.

However, you could/can give ctrl-F5 a try - that will launch your site as non debug mode (and you not that no stop button is highlight).

IIS "express" is a great setup for f5, step code, debug code. However, the instant you want to start testing the site, and not having launched it from "inside" of VS? Then you probably should setup a VM with the full edition of IIS, or even I suppose install full edition of IIS on your computer (I not done that, since I have a few VM's, and I don't want to "mess up" my developer box with having a full pop full edition of IIS installed on my computer.

So, if you want "others" to test the site, then setup a VM with server 2019, or whatever, and then install IIS full edition. This THEN gives you the full GUI and setup features of a web server - which is a good learning experience.

So when using f5 to debug? yes, a halt in code will halt the ability of the web server to dish out other pages. In effect, IIS process one page at a time, and when the page life cycle is done, the the next page/request can be processed.
So, if you want "more" then this setup, then you probably need/want to get a full blown full edition of IIS up and running. And I suggest that should be placed on some other computer then your dev box, or at the very least in a VM on your dev box.

You "can" sort of get IIS Express edition to be launched and running outside of a VS debug session, but it is painfully, since you don't have the GUI and all of the web configuration tools that the full edition of IIS has.

Comment: I think you misunderstood - yes, of course IIS will not respond when execution halts or the server is shutdown. The problem is that if I F5 to start it up again and refresh or open a new tab and browse, Chrome will not load the page until I shut down Chrome entirely as explained. There is something that happens that causes Chrome to stop working for that session after this happens.

Comment: hum, perhaps live preview is on? (or do you have more then one browser - can you launch a different one when hitting f5. (change the default browser that vs uses, see if that helps).

Comment: I always close the tab that VS opens, since it's the wrong URL - different login pages etc. I manually browse to what I need. New browser works, until I do have to halt and end again, then that one breaks.

Comment: do try (check) tools->options->web form designer->select "legacy web forms designer". (don't know if this will help - but try/check the setting, and don't use live web preview.

Comment: Legacy Web Forms designer is ticked already. I don't tend to use the designer anyway it's all hand written.